# Edit all strings in a html doc with beautifulsoup 4 in python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Let's say we have a html doc like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="c1">division
    <p>
    passage in division
    <b>bold in passage </b>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to prepend a word "cool " to  **each** string
(or NavigableString in bs4 terminology) in the html doc.

I have tried to walk through every element and check if it
has any children, if not then edit the string. This is inaccurate,
besides, the editing didn't take any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all text nodes in the document by calling [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) with [`text=True`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) argument. Use [`replace_with()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) to replace the text nodes with the modified text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="c1">division
    <p>
    passage in division
    <b>bold in passage </b>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for element in soup.find_all(text=True):
    text = element.string.strip()
    if text:
        element.replace_with("cool " + text)

print soup.prettify()
```

Prints:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   cool title
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="c1">
   cool division
   <p>
    cool passage in division
    <b>
     cool bold in passage
    </b>
   </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome. Is there a way to leave all `<script>` tags out?

Comment: @qed you can use `find_parent()`. For example, `if not element.find_parent('script'):` ...